# How does one get $p=2$ from a condition that there be non-trivial linear transformations of every dimension that to any power are $p$-norm-preserving?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving, alternative-proof

Verifying that (p=2) satisfies

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+.\exists A\in(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\setminus\{I_n\}).\forall k\in\mathbb{R}.\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.\left\|A^kv\right\|_p\!\!=\left\|v\right\|_p$$

is trivial (let each $A$ be a rotation matrix), but is there a clean way to obtain the value two from this condition?

(Note that $A^k$ is ambiguous for some choices of $A$ and $k$.  I believe that the solution set is the same regardless of how this ambiguity is resolved, even if such an $A^k$ is taken to be undefined.)

Related, but not (I believe) duplicates:

- [Why do we use the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221367/)
- [Why is the 2 norm “special”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452836/)
- [Why is the Euclidean metric the natural choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185038/)

Probably related:

- [This Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law)

Comment: I was assuming $k$ was an integer in my now-deleted answer. Yes, I see you specified $k\in\Bbb R$, sorry. That makes it a totally different question. Of course the _definition_ of $A^k$ for non-integer $k$ is problematic. But one could rephrase the question in terms of the existence of a "one-parameter group"  $\{A_k:k\in\Bbb R\}$ of isometries. What the answer is then I'm not so sure, but it seems probably yes - surely the isometry group is discrete for $p\ne 2$. Probably someone else can give a smoother proof than what I'd concoct...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Okay.  Thank you for the time you took on that first answer.  I admit that I'm playing fast and loose with $A^k$ in the write-up; it just seems unlikely to me that the choice in how to resolve the ambiguity could affect the set of solutions.